# Spring MVC application is not working with latest Java 11 version (Amazon corretto 11 [11.0.11.9.1])

Tags: java, java-11, corretto

I am working on Java upgrade version task with Spring MVC application. We are upgrading application from Java 8 to 11 and it works fine.

The application works fine with version `Java 11 (Amazon corretto 11 -> 11.0.7.10.1/11.0.8.10.1/11.0.9.11.1)` but when we switch it to version `11.0.10.9.1 or 11.0.11.9.1 (latest)` then it is not working. There is NO error or exception in the log. The application is not loading and it gets stuck somewhere. On browser, it loops in infinite.

Similar issue is there with Open JDK 11 Zulu provider. It works fine with 11.0.5 version but not with latest version.

Any workaround?

Comment: While debugging code, found that - it gets stuck while loading hibernate session factory. What exactly changed related to hibernate in between version 11.0.9.11.1 and 11.0.10.9.1? Do I need add any dependency in POM file? Currently we are using Hibernate version as '3.6.10.Final'.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the log or the error message?  Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of Hibernate?  The Hibernate Release website[1](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/) claims you need to upgrade to at least version 5.3.

Comment: Yes, after upgrading compatible Hibernate version (5.3.x), it is working fine. There were other code changes too but main reason was Hibernate upgrade.